# In Ubuntu, Why the sequence is changed?

Tags: multithreading, ubuntu, operating-system, sleep

I compile this code in Ubuntu. I did it more than 10 times but I got only AAA BBB CCC . I believe sequence can be changed but I don't know why. Please somebody kindly tell me the reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_entry(void *ptr)
{
char *name = (char *)ptr;

printf("%s-A\n", name);

sleep(1); //sched_yield();

printf("%s-B\n", name);

sleep(1); //sched_yield();

printf("%s-C\n", name);


}

int main()
{
#define MAX_THREAD  3
pthread_t thread[MAX_THREAD];
char *thread_name[MAX_THREAD] = {"thread1", "thread2", "thread3"};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, thread_entry, thread_name[i]);

for (i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it's possible, but it's very unlikely you would see another ordering.

You spawn 3 threads, then one of them prints "A" and waits for 1 second until it will print "B". One second of sleeping is far more than enough for the rest threads to print "A". Same for "B" and "C".

Comment: I really appreciate of you. But if I make a 3threads to 5threads. Will it be easy to see another ordering?? I wonder why is it really hard to see the another ordering?? Thank you again!

Comment: And I wonder why the ordering is AAA BBB CCC commonly. Thank you again

Comment: You may try to use more threads and fewer time interval. (usleep() or even nanosleep() instead of sleep()). But the best solution would be remove sleep() compeltely. In fact you see different ordering each time: the order of threads printing each block seperately is different

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you!! I owe you